# Constraintlist with two Options Pyomo

Tags: optimization, constraint, pyomo

I recently started with Pyomo and I have the following Problem:

I want to construct a ConstraintList with an if statement.
I already learned, that it's not possible. But the problem still exists...
My first code (with the if statement) was the following one:

```
m.Constraint10=pyo.ConstraintList()
for i in m.Stunde:
  for j in m.Kraftwerk:
     if pyo.value(m.Kraftwerkseinsatz[i,j]) != 0:
        m.Constraint10.add(m.Kraftwerkseinsatz[i,j]>=m.MinOutput[j])
```

`m.Stunde` and `m. Kraftwerk` are indices.

`m.Kraftwerkseinsatz` is a variable!

`m.MinOutput` is a parameter.

In other words, my variable must be greater than the MinOutput parameter or zero (for every hour and every power plant).

I already thought of reframing the constraint like this:
`m.Kraftwerkseinsatz[i,j]` must not be between 0.1 and `m.MinOutput`.

But I don't know how to code this either. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variable that can assume values of zero or between some lower and upper bound is called a **semi-continuous variable**. Most high-end solvers have direct support for this type of variable. If not supported, you can model this with an additional binary variable:
$$\begin{align} & \color{darkblue}L\cdot \color{darkred}\delta \le \color{darkred}x \le \color{darkblue}U \cdot \color{darkred}\delta \\
& \color{darkred}\delta \in \{0,1\} \\ &\color{darkred}x\in [0,\color{darkblue}U]\end{align}$$

AFAIK, Pyomo has no direct support for semi-continuous variables. So the obvious approach is to use binary variables. An alternative would be to use Pyomo's Disjunctive Programming tools ([GDP](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modeling_extensions/gdp/index.html)).

Note: in the bounds for $\color{darkred}x$, I assumed $\color{darkblue}L\gt 0$. We can make this more general by stating $\color{darkred}x \in [\min(0,\color{darkblue}L),\max(0,\color{darkblue}U)]. $